# Returning element from dynamic map created in module A into module B

Tags: terraform

Suppose I have a module which outputs an ALB name and it's ARN:

```
output "this_alb_id_and_name" {
  value = "${zipmap(tolist(aws_alb.this.*.name),
  tolist(aws_alb.this.*.id))}"
}
```

How do I access the value with it's key? Currently I'm testing something along the lines of this:

```
module "nlb_listener" {
  #irrelevant module attributes...
  load_balancer_arn = module.nlb_instance[*].this_alb_id_and_name["the_alb_name_${count.index}"]
}
```

I suspect there's problems with using count and map or the key not being valid or something similar. I've not got the foggiest what I'm doing wrong, I've had errors about the map being invalid mostly and "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value."

Comment: Do you really want to be looping over creating multiple ALBs and then iterating over them to create multiple listeners in different modules? Why not create the listener at the same time as the ALB? It feels like what you're trying to do is probably overly complicated right now.

Comment: To be answerable though you probably need to include slightly more Terraform code than you have right now. Ideally it should take the form of a [mcve] so you should show you are looping over the ALB resource and then how you are using it in the `nlb_listener` resource.

Comment: That's fine - I've fixed this now.